# In Spring Boot 3.1.1 how to sole '.and()' , '.sessionManagement()', 'authorizeHttpRequests()' is deprecated and marked for removal?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Hello I have an application develop with Spring Boot 3.1.1. My spring security configuration that worked fine with Spring Boot 3.0.6 no longer works. and many things have been depreciated. ".and().build()", "csrf()", "authorizeHttpRequests()", "sessionManagement()" are deprecated and marked for removal, What are the alternatives? Below is my code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    private static final String USER = "USER";

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,
                                             UserDetailsService userDetailsService)
            throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .cors().configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

                    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
                    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    config.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
                    config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                    return config;
                }).and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/list/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/v1/delete/**").hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/v1/update/**").hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/get/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN, USER)
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Comment: The javadoc of the deprecated methods tell you **exactly** what the replacements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conform documentation, you can do what you want by using  [`DSL`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html#_use_the_lambda_dsl)

Your current impl will look so:

```
http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .sessionManagement(c -> c.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .cors(c -> c.configurationSource(
                request -> {
                  CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

                  config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
                  config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                  config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                  config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                  config.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
                  config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                  return config;
                }))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(c ->
                    c.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/list/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/v1/delete/**").hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/v1/update/**").hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/get/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN, USER)
                    .anyRequest().authenticated());
http.addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
http.addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
return http.build();
```